# Regex Match whole word string in coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Im trying this example

first example

```
keyword = "star"; 
myString = "The dog sniffed at the star fish and growled";
regEx = "\b"& keyword &"\b"; 
if (reFindNoCase(regEx, myString)) { 
     writeOutput("found it"); 
} else { 
     writeOutput("did not find it"); 
}
```

Example  output -> found it

second example

```
keyword = "star"; 
myString = "The dog sniffed at the .star fish and growled";
regEx = "\b"& keyword &"\b"; 
if (reFindNoCase(regEx, myString)) { 
     writeOutput("found it"); 
} else { 
     writeOutput("did not find it"); 
}
```

output -> found it

but i want to find only whole word. punctuation issue for me how can i using regex  for  second example  output: did not find it

Comment: Try using this workaround: `regEx = "(^|\W)"& keyword &"(?=\W|$)";`

Comment: @mlk, the language is coldfusion.  It runs on coldfusion application server, which is written in java.

Comment: @EgemenAtes: Please let me know if my suggestion works for you.

Comment: @stribizhev not working for me.Im solving this command `<cfset regEx = "\s\b" & TABLE_NAME & "\b\s">`

Comment: But did you try `<cfset regEx = "(^|\W)"& keyword &"(?=\W|$)">`? Why doesn't it work? What is the output you get? Note that `\b`s around TABLE_NAME will prevent `.star` from matching.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check. I think the grouping is necessary to make sure we can match the strings at the start and end of string.

Answer (score 5):

Coldfusion does not support lookbehind, so, you cannot use a real "zero-width boundary" check.  Instead, you can use groupings (and fortunately a lookahead):

```
regEx = "(^|\W)"& keyword &"(?=\W|$)";
```

Here, `(^|\W)` matches either the start of a string, and `(?=\W|$)` makes sure there is either a non-word character (`\W`) or the end of string (`$`).

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oX5zT6/1)

However, make sure you escape your keyword before passing to the regex. See [*ColdFusion 10 now provides reEscape() to prepare string literals for native RE-methods*](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2355-coldfusion-10---reescape-vs-java-pattern-s-quote-method.htm).

Another way is to match spaces or start/end of string:

```
<cfset regEx = "(^|\s)" & TABLE_NAME & "($|\s)">
```

Comment: Great tip about reEscape! I was not aware of that one.